# Android Room SQlite MVVM: Return a PK after insert and capture PK in a var to pass to other Activities

Tags: android, sqlite, mvvm, android-sqlite, android-room

Trying to get the insert to return the PK so I can capture it in a var and pass it to other activities.

DAO:

```
 @Dao public interface NoteDao {
 @Insert
 long insert(Note note);
```

Repository:

```
private MutableLiveData<Long> noteInsertedLiveData = new MutableLiveData();
private NoteDao noteDao;
private LiveData<List<Note>> allNotes;


public NoteRepository(Application application) {

    NoteDatabase database = NoteDatabase.getInstance(application);
    noteDao = database.noteDao();
    allNotes = noteDao.getAllNotes2();
}

public void insert(OnTaskCompleted onTaskCompleted, Note note) {

    new InsertAsyncTask(noteDao, onTaskCompleted).execute(note);

}
public LiveData<Long> getNoteInsertedLiveData() {
    return noteInsertedLiveData;
}
```

ASync:

```
  private static class InsertNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Long> {


    private long sqCbtId = -1;
    private NoteDao noteDao;
    private OnTaskCompleted onTaskCompleted;


    private InsertNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao, OnTaskCompleted onTaskCompleted) {
        this.noteDao = noteDao;
        this.onTaskCompleted = onTaskCompleted;
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Note... notes) {

        return noteDao.insert(notes[0])
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

        onTaskCompleted.onTaskCompleted(result);
    }
}
```

View model:

```
public long insert(Note note){
sqCbtId = repository.insert(note); return sqCbtId; }
```

Activity :

```
Note note = new Note(userId, therapistId, automaticThoughtString, distortions, challengeThoughtString, alternativeThoughtString, postedWorkout);
sqCbtId = noteViewModel.insert(note);
```

Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "note_table")
public class Note {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "cbtId")
private long sqCbtId;

@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "userId")
private int userId;

@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "therapistId")
private int therapistId;

@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "automaticThought")
private String automaticThought;

@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "distortions")
private int distortions;

@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "challengeThought")
private String challengeThought;

@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "alternativeThought")
private String alternativeThought;

@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "postedWorkout")
private String postedWorkout;
```

I have one error on this line:

new InsertAsyncTask(noteDao, onTaskCompleted).execute(note)

It states that the InsertASyncTask cannot be applied to the paramteters (naoteDao, onTaskCompleted)

Comment: Please provide the entity class. Can update my answer based on the same.

Comment: entity class edited into the answer, i left out the constructor and getters/setters to save space

Answer (score 1):

SQLite and hence Room's `@Insert` implementation returns the row id of the inserted row. If the primary key is not auto generated you already know it, provided inserted didn't return `-1` which signifies error. If the Primary key is auto generated you would need to query it again.

Since your Primary Key is of type `long`, ie, `INTEGER` for SQLite, the rowId becomes the Primary Key for the row. See this: https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html

Hence in this case you do not need to query again for the Primary Key. Simply use the rowId returned by `@Insert` (provided not `-1`).

Errors on your code:

```
sqCbtId = note.getSqCbtId(); return sqCbtId;
```

This is getting the `sqCbtId` from the object you have just inserted into the database. The id is not generated for this object. It is stored in database. Get the id from the `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute`

Code: (ignore any compilation errors or typo, not written on IDE :P)

```
class ViewModel
{
    private MutableLiveData<Long> noteInsertedLiveData = new MutableLiveData();

    public long insert(Note note) {

        new InsertNoteAsyncTask(noteDao, new InsertNoteAsyncTask.Listener {
            @override
            void onNoteInserted(Long sqCbtId) {
                noteInsertedLiveData.setValue(sqCbtId);
            }
        }).execute(note);
        sqCbtId = note.getSqCbtId(); return sqCbtId; 

    }

    public LiveData<Long> getNoteInsertedLiveData() {
        return noteInsertedLiveData;
    }

    private static class InsertNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Long> {

        private long sqCbtId = -1;
        private NoteDao noteDao;
        private Listener listener;

        private InsertNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao, Listener listener) {
            this.noteDao = noteDao; 
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(Note... notes) {
        sqCbtId = noteDao.insert(notes[0]);
        return sqCbtId;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            listener.onNoteInserted(result);
        }

        interface Listener {
            void onNoteInserted(Long sqCbtId);
        }
    }
}
```

On your Activity

```
noteViewModel.getNoteInsertedLiveData().observe(this, /** add Observer here to get update on id after every insert in db **/);


Note note = new Note(userId, therapistId, automaticThoughtString, distortions, challengeThoughtString, alternativeThoughtString, postedWorkout);
noteViewModel.insert(note);
```

Comment: But how do i get this pk ID in the activity? it just displays 0 even though the row is insert correctly into the db.

Comment: Your `AsyncTask` needs to return `sqCbtId` instead of `null`

Comment: Furthermore I do not see the code where your Activity is expecting the return type or observing on the data in DB

Comment: Im a beginner at this can you show me what I should write in the onPostExecute method. I don't know what code I should put in there to obtain the PK ID

Comment: Updated. with code. However you should read on `LiveData` and Observer pattern in Java for future references.

Comment: new InsertNoteAsyncTask(noteDao, new InsertNoteAsyncTask.Listener 

AsyncTask does not have a .Listener option available. Im assuming you meant to put that in the repository class also instead of the view model as all the Async tasks occur in my repository class.

Comment: Ah yes. Basically have an interface for callbacks from the AsyncTask

Comment: I cannot get your code working at all, the IDE is showing errors everywhere and I'm not experienced enough to know what to change to make it work. I understand what  you are trying to do but I cant make your answer work due to the small errors in it. Can you copy it into an IDE and fix it up?

Comment: share your code on github gist or a sample project. Right now unable to check this out on IDE

Comment: I missed passing `Listener ` on the Async Task constructor. Type :P

Comment: Updated. See this `private InsertNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao, Listener listener)` line

Comment: new InsertNoteAsyncTask(noteDao, new InsertNoteAsyncTask.Listener {

That line of code doesnt work, you cant pass listener here
Also in your interface im assuming its suppose ot be void because other wise the IDE wants a return??

Comment: The interface should specify return type. Sorry! I write Kotlin mainly and these stupid errors come up

Comment: public void insert(Note note) {

        new InsertNoteAsyncTask(noteDao, new InsertNoteAsyncTask.Listener{
            @override

This Listener is red, it wont let me call it here. the Async code is now wokring with no errors showing. Its just this first part now at the top

Comment: Going by your code on Github it should be `OnTaskCompleted`

Comment: It doesnt allow anything to be passed there except a few things like .cast, .var, .field .instance of, It will not allow me to instantiate anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static class InsertNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void> {

    private long sqCbtId = -1;
    private NoteDao noteDao;
    private Context context;

    private InsertNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao) {
        this.noteDao = noteDao;

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Note... notes) {
        sqCbtId = noteDao.insert(notes[0]);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        getCbtId(sqCbtId);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: " + sqCbtId);

    }

    public void getCbtId(long cbtId) {
        sqCbtId = cbtId;
    }
}
```

This is the code I used which captures the row id